# How can I send a signal to LEDs from my Android 4.2.2 device? (Eclipse & USB cable)

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, controls, circuit

I am trying to use my Android 4.2.2 in order to illuminate my LED circuit. I can do this with y microprossessor, so why couldn't do this with Android? I want to touch a button than make an open signal, then send this through the USB cable to my LED circuit.

I am electronics engineering student. Is there any Android codes to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on about controlling your LED by perhaps holding Data+ USB pin high or something like this? http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549

Comment: Yes! I am on about to control my LED, and yes holding&/sending datas through my USB cable. Data+ Data - I mean. Yes I saw the link which you added, but I haven't got Arduino therminal.

Comment: I can only think of a crude way of doing this and that would be to use a USB cable on your device and strip the ends into your development board. You could then write an app that would constantly send data on the data+ line (should be a few examples on goggle). I'm sure there is a better way though, just needs some research.